# In Windows shell scripting (cmd.exe) how do you assign the stdout of a program to an environment variable?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

In UNIX you can assign the output of a script to an environment variable using the technique explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115615/assigning-value-to-shell-variable-using-a-function-return-value-from-python) - but what is the Windows equivalent?

I have a python utility which is intended to correct an environment variable. This script simply writes a sequence of chars to stdout. For the purposes of this question, the fact that my utility is written in python is irrelevant, it's just a program that I can call from the command-prompt which outputs a single line of text.

I'd like to do something like this (that works):

```
set WORKSPACE=[ the output of my_util.py ]
```

After running this command the value of the WORKSPACE environment variable should contain the exact same text that my utility would normally print out.

Can it be done? How?

---

UPDATE1: Somebody at work suggested:

```
python util.py | set /P WORKSPACE=
```

In theory, that would assign the stdout of the python-script top the env-var WORKSPACE, and yet it does not work, what is going wrong here?

Comment: It has already been asked - [How do I get the result of a command in a variable in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('<insert command here>') do @set <variable name>=%A
```

For example:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('time /t') do @set my_env_var=%A
```

...will run the command "time /t" and set the env variable "my_env_var" to the result.

Remember to use %%A instead of %A if you're running this inside a .BAT file.

Comment: Wow, that's some fugly scripting but it just might work. I'm going to try it now!

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of %%A rather than %A in the context of a batch file?

Comment: In batch files, "%" is a reservered character.  For example, %1 refers to the first argument passed on the command line.  So, in cases where you need to use a "%" where you're not referring to command line arguments, you double it up like "%%".

Comment: This is one of the ugliest trick I often have to use. It's amazing how often in batch you have to use features intended for completely different uses to supply to the fundamental things that are missing.

Comment: Keep in mind though, that if the command has more than a single line of output you will only retain the last one in the variable.