# How do I concatenate contents of a file to an environment variable in Windows Command prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables

Assuming 'paths' is a file containing all the paths I need to write to the environment variable `CLASSPATH`, appended in the right format. I essentially need Windows equivalent of

```
CLASSPATH=$(cat paths)
```

In accordance with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738673/in-windows-shell-scripting-cmd-exe-how-do-you-assign-the-stdout-of-a-program-t) answer I tried doing the below:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('cat paths.txt') do @set CLASSPATH=%A
```

(paths.txt has all the paths in the right format) but it does not work. Echoing '%CLASSPATH%' still gives me nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This in a .bat file would produce `p1;p2;p3;`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set CLASSPATH=
for /f "delims=" %%A in (paths.txt) do set "CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!%%A;"
echo %CLASSPATH%

rem to make it a permanent global
setx CLASSPATH %CLASSPATH%
```