# How to return values to korn shell from python?

Tags: python, shell, ksh

I have a korn shell script that calls in a Python script.
The Python script should return a variable length list of strings.
The ksh should capture those strings and do some more processing.
How do I return the list and capture it??

My current code:

**Python test.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

list = [ 'the quick brown fox', 'jumped over the lazy', 'dogs' ]
for s in list:
        print s
```

**Korn script test.ksh:**

```
#!/bin/ksh
IFS=$'\n'
echo $IFS

for line in $(test.py)
do
echo "\nline:"
echo "$line"
done
```

**Output:**

> test.ksh

```
 \

line:
the quick brow

line:
 fox
jumped over the lazy
dogs
```

Comment: Follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115615/assigning-value-to-shell-variable-using-a-function-return-value-from-python

Comment: That ~ALMOST~ answers my need. but, how do I separate the list items inside the korn shell?

Comment: @Radamand See the answers showing how to set IFS to newline (only) – they will solve this part of the problem.

Comment: got it, thanks!  had to use "IFS=${IFS#??}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: use a for loop, subshell invocation (see [assigning value to shell variable using a function return value from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115615/assigning-value-to-shell-variable-using-a-function-return-value-from-python)), and set the IFS to just newline.

See the following demonstrations:

First, create a python program that prints a variable-length list of strings:

> ```
> $ cat > stringy.py
> list = [ 'the quick brown fox', 'jumped over the lazy', 'dogs' ]
> for s in list:
>     print s
> import sys
> sys.exit(0)
> <ctrl-D>
> ```

Demonstrate that it works:

> ```
> $ python stringy.py
> the quick brown fox
> jumped over the lazy
> dogs
> ```

Launch ksh:

> ```
> $ ksh
> ```

Example #1: for loop, invoking subshell, standard IFS, no quoting:

> ```
> $ for line in $(python stringy.py) ; do echo "$line" ; done # Edited: added double-quotes
> the
> quick
> brown
> fox
> jumped
> over
> the
> lazy
> dogs
> ```

Example #2: for loop, invoking subshell, standard IFS, quoting:

> ```
> $ for line in "$(python stringy.py)" ; do echo "$line" ; done # Edited: added double-quotes
> the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
> ```

Example #3: for loop, invoking subshell, no quoting, IFS set to just newline:

> ```
> $ IFS=$'\n'
> $ echo $IFS
>
> $ for line in $(python stringy.py) ; do echo $line ; done # Edited: added double-quotes
> the quick brown fox
> jumped over the lazy
> dogs
> ```

Example #3 demonstrates how to solve the problem.

Comment: inside the loop, quote `"$line"` -- sequences of whitespace and tabs will get collapsed to a single space otherwise.

Comment: @glenn Technically, that is not correct in this **particular** instance, since `echo` handles a variable number of arguments, echoing them all.  **But**, you make an **important** point: I agree 100% that if you were passing the args to a non-varargs function/executable then you would want to put double-quotes around the variable.  I.e., if you were invoking `foo` instead of `echo`, then you would write `foo "$line"` instead of `foo $line`.  Let me reiterate: it is better to quote it.  I will edit the answer to show `echo "$line"` instead of `echo $line`.

Comment: I mean this: `x="   foo     bar    baz   "` -- then `echo $x` and `echo "$x"` give you different results. In many situations that's significant.

Comment: @glennjackman YES, YOU ARE CORRECT, MY MISTAKE: the shell word-breaks the string and then the `echo` echoes each of the resulting "words" with a space between them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for l in $list; do
    echo "$l
done
```

More specifically:

```
for l in "${list[@]}"; do
    echo "$l
done
```

Comment: how is $list populated? Missing close quote in your echo statement.

Comment: how it's populated that I already answered in the comment just after the question!

Comment: Since the question is "how do I capture the output", a useful answer would explicitly show how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The python script will just print stuff to stdout.

The ksh part will read each line into an array:

```
typeset -a values
python scrypt.py | while IFS= read -r line; do
    values+=( "$line" )
done

echo the first value is: "${value[0]}"
echo there are ${#value[@]} values.
```

Here's a different technique

```
output=$( python scrypt.py )
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
lines=( $output )
IFS=$oldIFS
```

---

ksh88:

```
typeset -i i=0
python scrypt.py | while IFS= read -r line; do
    lines[i]="$line"
    i=i+1
done

echo the first line is: "${lines[0]}"
echo there are ${#lines[@]} lines
echo the lines:
printf "%s\n" "${lines[@]}"
```

When a variable has the "integer" attribute (variable `i`), assignments to it are implicitly done in arithmetic context, so the magical `i=i+1` works.

Comment: Upvoted for demonstrating save-and-restore of the IFS.

Comment: doesn't even run;

syntax error at line 4 : `(' unexpected

Comment: removing the parenthesis causes it to print each word on a separate line.

Comment: ksh: typeset: bad option(s)

Comment: what version of ksh are you running?

Comment: > [ "${ERRNO}" ] && echo ksh88 || echo ksh99
= ksh88