# How to return a value from jython script to shell scripts?

Tags: shell, jython

I just need to return this `seg` value to shell script. Here's my code:

```
import os
certificate1=AdminTask.listPersonalCertificates('[-keyStoreName
NodeDefaultKeyStore -keyStoreScope (cell):h1423Cell01:(node):h1423Node01 ]')
temp=certificate1
seg=temp[-16:-5]

print seg
```

Comment: I wonder, what do you mean by 'return'?  Looks like you're already printing the value to `stdout`.  If you capture that value in your calling script, you're all set.

Comment: I am having shell script which is calling my jython script .I just want to send the seg variable value to my shell script to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [assigning value to shell variable using a function return value from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115615/assigning-value-to-shell-variable-using-a-function-return-value-from-python)